# What transitive action of a permutation group connects the Prufer 2-group?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions, symmetric-groups

Let $X$ be the dyadic rationals in the half-open unit interval.

The graph $G$ over $X$ having the vertices $(x,x+2^{\nu_2(x)-1})$ and $(x,x-2^{\nu_2(x)-1})$ is connected.  It's just the infinite binary rooted tree and the proof it's connected is that it maps each number to its square in the Prufer 2-group, which is torsion.

Suppose we didn't know a priori that $G$ is connected, what exchanges of pairs of elements would need to be defined in the spirit of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209373/transitivity-on-mathbbn-0-a-42-problem) in order to define a subgroup of the permutation group, which acts transitively on $X$ if and only if $G$ is connected?

The motivation is for me to understand better, by virtue of an example I understand, how the transitivity property is being used in that question.

Is it as simple as exchanging the two ends of each edge?